# How to load dynamic module in current page?

Tags: react-native

I am new to RN, I am doing a test page, press a button to load diff module.
not like .

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._loadM.bind(this,0)}>
<Text style={styles.switchItemTxt}>item0</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._loadM.bind(this,1)}>
<Text style={styles.switchItemTxt}>item1</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<ScrollView style={styles.scrolls} automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}>
//if item0 pressed load ModuleOne
<ModuleOne />
// else load ModuleTwo
<ModuleTwo />
</ScrollView>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: not like TabBarIOS....

Answer (score 0):

Answer myself:

```
var CurrentMoudle = require('./module1');

_loadM(e) {
switch (e) {
  case 0:
    CurrentMoudle = require('./module1');
    break;
  case 1:
    CurrentMoudle = require('./module2');
    break;
  default:
    CurrentMoudle = require('./module1');
    break;
}
// reload page
this.forceUpdate();
}


<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._loadM.bind(this,0)}>
   <Text>item1</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._loadM.bind(this,1)}>
   <Text>持仓</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<ScrollView style={styles.scrolls}>
   <CurrentMoudle />
</ScrollView>
```